# SQLite writes [object object] instead string

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

I created a class named `Table` in javascipt, and it has `CREATE()` `INSERT_MANY()` method. The `CREATE()` method is for creating tables and table columns, and `INSERT_MANY()` is for inserting data into tables.

This is the `INSERT_MANY()` method:

```js
/**
 * Performs a task that inserts data into an sqlite3 table.
 * Each object must have the same property as the column name in the table.
 * @param {Array<Object>} data - An Array of object for the values to insert into the table.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves to an object with information about the newly created table or rejects with an error message.
 */
INSERT_MANY(data) {
    if( Array.isArray(data) === false ) return Promise.reject('Data argument must be an array.')

    if( data.every(x => Object.keys(x).every(y => this.column.find(z => z.name === y))) === false ) return reject('Properties name must be same as column name.')

    let manualMode =  this.column.filter(x => x.mode === 'MANUAL').map(x => x.name)
    let defaultMode =  this.column.filter(x => x.mode === 'DEFAULT').map(x => x.name)
    manualMode = manualMode.map(val => `${val}`).join(',')

    let i = 0
    const $data = data.map(x => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(x).map(key => ({ [`$${key}${i++}`]: x[key] }))))

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const db = new sqlite3.Database(this.dir)

        i = 0
        const values = data.map(val => `(${Object.keys(val).map(val => `$${val}${i++}`).join(',')})`).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + ',' + curr)
        const query = `INSERT INTO ${this.name} ${defaultMode.length > 0 ? `(${manualMode})` : ''} VALUES ${values}`
        db.serialize(() => {
            db.run(query, $data, err => {
                    
                if(err) {
                    console.log(`query: "${query}"`)
                    return reject(err)
                }
                return resolve(data)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I have looked at the documentation on sqlite3-nodejs, and it says that I should add $ for the placeholder if my params argument is object

This is my code that calls the `INSERT_MANY()` method:

```js
mainTable.INSERT_MANY([{ path: 'path1', name: 'name1' }, { path: 'path2', name: 'name2' }, { path: 'path3', name: 'name3' }]).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

But SQLite db writes [object object] instead data that I gave.

I want to know, why the db is returns [object object] instead of string.

Can someone explain me and fix it?